# Why does signing commit with SSH key fail with "invalid format?" and "failed to write commit object"?

Tags: git, ssh-keys, signing, git-for-windows

I followed [GitHub's instructions](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/managing-commit-signature-verification/telling-git-about-your-signing-key#telling-git-about-your-ssh-key) for telling git about my SSH key, but when I tried to sign a commit

```
git commit -S
```

I got this error:

```
error: Load key 
"C:\\Users\\MyName\\AppData\\Local\\Temp/.git_signing_key_tmpC5KwFc": invalid format?

fatal: failed to write commit object
```

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Note that the "failed to write commit object" is merely fallout from the earlier failure. Still, good idea to include both in the question, for searchability!

Comment: you may reference to github's offical doc https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent, it helps me a lot

Answer (score 23):

### Setup

For Git to successfully sign the commit,

1. Git (v2.34 or later) needs to [know about your SSH key](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/managing-commit-signature-verification/telling-git-about-your-signing-key#telling-git-about-your-ssh-key)
2. The ssh-agent needs to be running

   - `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` to start it
   - (Windows can be [told to auto-start](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases?platform=windows#auto-launching-ssh-agent-on-git-for-windows) it; Mac and Linux already do.)
3. The ssh-agent needs to have your key

   - `ssh-add -L` to list existing keys
   - `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519` to [add your key](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent)

### Signing

Then you should be able to sign the commit!

`git commit -S`

### Verifying

More on [verifying your SSH-signed commits](https://calebhearth.com/sign-git-with-ssh#:%7E:text=configured%20signing%20correctly.-,Verifying,-Git%20also%20lets).

Comment: My issue was resolved when I added my RSA key to ssh-agent.

Answer (score 0):

### These steps fix the issues for me

1. [Test your SSH connection](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/testing-your-ssh-connection)
2. Test if the SSH key added to the ssh-agent

```bash
# you must see the public key in the output 
ssh-add -l
```

- Then compare the output of :
  `ssh-add -l -E sha256`
  with [githupe ssh key](https://github.com/settings/keys)
  , if the same then your ssh key is added correctly to the ssh-agent.

3. Turn auto start for the `ssh-agent` service

- Search for the services in the search bar then find the two ssh service

  `OpenSSH Authentication Agent`

  `OpenSSH SSH Server`
- `click right > priority > change startup to : automatique + change service status to : start >  apply > ok`

Or you can add a [simple code](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases#:%7E:text=a%20new%20passphrase.-,Auto%2Dlaunching%20ssh%2Dagent%20on%20Git%20for%20Windows,-You%20can%20run) to your bashrc (git bash profile ) setting

> you can find the git bash profile in :  `C:\Program Files\Git\etc ---> bash.bashrc`

4. (re)added the SSH key to `ssh-agent` with `ssh-add --apple-use-keychain ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_github`
5. Make sure you that the format of publique key file `id_ed25519.pub` and private key file `id_ed25519` is `UTF-8`
6. Delete the ssh key from GitHub setting and [add](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account) it again
7. [Telling Git about your SSH key](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/managing-commit-signature-verification/telling-git-about-your-signing-key#:%7E:text=Signing%20commits.%22-,Telling%20Git%20about%20your%20SSH%20key,-You%20can%20use) ( **This is the most important step**)